# Displaying data frame rows in sentence structure

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple pandas data frame with 3 columns: Num, Question, Answer:

```
Num        Question Answer
 1   What is your favorite color? Green
 2  Favorite sport? Basketball
```

Basically I just want to present each row of this dataframe in a sentence structure like the following:

```
Question #1: What is your favorite color? Answer: Green
Question #2: Favorite sport? Answer: Basketball
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iterrows`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Question": ['What is your favorite color?', 'Favorite sport?'],
                   "Answer": ['Green', 'Basketball'],
                   "Num": [1, 2]})

for _, row in df.iterrows():
    print("Question #{0}: {1} Answer: {2}".format(
        row['Num'], row['Question'], row['Answer']))

# Output:
# Question #1: What is your favorite color? Answer: Green
# Question #2: Favorite sport? Answer: Basketball
```